# JQ: how to delete field if null or not exist?

Tags: null, key, jq, exists, del

I need to delete field if it's null or not exist. Json looks like:

```
{
    "response": {
        "somefield1": 0,
        "somefield2": 0,
        "somefield3": 0.0,
        "somefield4": [{
            "somefield5": "abc",
            "somefield6": "123",
            "TheField": ["\u0000\"{\"id\":\"123,SomeFields\":{\"SomeField\":{some data}}}\"\u0000"]
        }]
    }
}
```

JQ

```
{
        SomeField: "%s",
        SomeField1: "%s",
        SomeField2: "a",
        SomeField3: "b",
        SomeField4: {
            a: "%s",
            b: "%s"
        },
        SomeField5: "%s",
      SomeField6: .response?.somefield4[]?.TheField[]?,
} | del(.SomeField6? | nulls)
```

So if "TheField" doesn't exist or it's null I need to delete SomeField6. Right now instead of delete current field JQ delete all statement and I get nothing on response.

Comment: What does it mean to delete the field if it does not exist? Can you post a clear input JSON and an expected output

Comment: I mean if "TheField" doesn't exist or it's null then I need to delete or not add SomeField6 to response. Request and response I add above.

Answer (score 1):

> how to delete field if null or not exist?

If $o is an object which may or may not have a key, say $k, then to delete the key if its value is null, and leave $o as-is otherwise, you could write:

```
$o | if .[$k] == null then del(.[$k]) else . end
```

or if the key is sufficiently simple (basically alphanumeric with leading alpha, where "alpha" includes "_"), you could write an expression along the lines of:

```
$o | if .k == null then del(.k) else . end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the field and then deleting it, you could simply create it conditionally.

A simple and robust (w.r.t. versions of jq) method for conditionally adding a key, $k, to an object, $o, is to use the template:

```
$o + (if CONDITION then {($k): $value} else null end)
```

where CONDITION and $value each evaluates to a single value.

So in your case, you could write something like:

```
((try first(.response.somefield4[].TheField[]) catch null) // null) as $value
. + (if $value then {SomeField6: $value} else null end)
```